# Questions about Lagrangian and consumer's problem

Tags: microeconomics, lagrangian

Background: Suppose a consumer has the following utility function $u(x,y)=\sqrt{xy}$, then the Lagrangian equation is $\mathcal{L}(x,y)=\sqrt{xy}+\lambda(I-xp_x-yp_y)$. Then the optimal bundle is $(x,y)^*=(\frac{I}{2p_x},\frac{I}{2p_y})$ and $\lambda^*=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{p_xp_y}}$.

Question 1): For $x^*,y^*$,I know how to get those,i.e. by solving $\frac{\frac{\partial{u_x}}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial{u_y}}{\partial y}}$ and plugging into income equation. I am not sure how to calculate to get $\lambda^*$.

Please let me know what context to add to make questions clearer, thanks.

Comment: 1. "$\lambda^*=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{p_xp_y}}$" ,,, " I  am not sure how to get $\lambda$"  ?

Comment: 2. I am not sure I understand your question here either. It would be surprising if this formula for $(x,y)*$ would work for every single utility maximization problem; in this sense it is not indeed not *general*. You can indeed verify this by solving the problem for any utility function representing different preferences.

Comment: @Giskard It was on lecture notes, it wrote that the optimal lagrange multiplier was $\lambda^*$. I deleted Question 2, since I figured out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint for Question 1.

Taking the partial derivative of the Lagrangian with respect to $x$ and setting it equal to zero you should have obtained:

$$\frac{x^{-1/2}y^{1/2}}{2}-\lambda p_x=0$$

Then you can substitute the optimal values of $x$ and $y$ and solve for $\lambda$.  Can you take it from there?